# Arduino Code is slow when running two task

Tags: arduino-uno

[image: This is the code]

- I want pin 11 to give a square wave of once 3 sec
- and want pin 12 to act as a switch to glow pin 13 Built in led..
- connected pin 12 to GND with 10k resistor

If i fed the switch code alone it is fast(the led turn on instantly), but when i fed this code (the on in picture) it has a 1 sec lag to turn on the led. why?

And also if i connect pin 11 to 12 i assume the builtin led should turn on and off according to the wave form coming out of  but the led is always low.

Comment: use this library https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/arduino-timer/

Comment: Or this https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/FlexiTimer2/  https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-tasking-the-arduino-part-2/timers

Comment: Just to try to confirm what exactly you're asking about: you've explicitly told it to do something, *delay for 3 seconds*, do something else, *delay for another 3 seconds* ... and now you're asking why there's a delay ... ?

Comment: No code as image please. Copy and paste the code as text into the question. Then you can format is as code so that it will be displayed correctly

Comment: Look at the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example that comes with the Arduino IDE, and at the `millis()` function. You can find many tutorials about that online. Basically you should not delay for long periods of time, since the arduino cannot do anything in that time. Use a non-blocking code style

Comment: @brhans bro i mean only the switch portion not the wave form..  if i turn on the switch there a 1 sec lag

Comment: @chrisl what language is ard ?? C or c++

Comment: Arduino code is C++

Comment: Your Arduino isn't going to even read the switch until the delay(s) are finished. So you're looking at a delay of up to 6 seconds in every loop where it's not reading the switch.

Comment: @brhans so first the blink code execute then only the switch code comes???

Comment: Please make sure that you _understand_ the code you have written. From your comments it does not seem so. As chrisl says, look at the blink example without delay, and _understand_ it. We can only give you hints, the learning is your task.

Comment: @yuvanm: Re “_first the blink code execute then only the switch code comes?_”: Indeed: the Arduino executes one statement at a time, in the order they are written. Whatever comes after `delay(3000);` is only executed once the Arduino is done with the delay.

Comment: @EdgarBonet thank you got it

Comment: OK everyone. You see the "answer" box below the question? That's where answers go. It is kind-of sad that this box is empty (at the time I write this) and a whole lot of useful answers are given as comments on the question. This is **not a forum**. Please do not answer in comments.

Comment: @yuvanm If you think you understand what the issue is, you can even answer your own question, thus helping future people who are wondering the same thing. Then people can vote on your answer, showing how good it is.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the code comprises Two Parts

1. Square Wave with 3-sec delay on and 3-sec delay off
2. if the pin 12, is high pin 13 will be high and if 12 is low 13 is also low(a simple on/off switch)

---

The second block of code executes only after the first Block of code is done executing.

That's why when I connected the pin 11 to 12 the led wasn't shining because when the WAVE code(that first block of code which gives a square wave) was running, the second block of code was quiet hence the 12th pin was still not become a switch yet.

And the delay I told was due to this, actually, the delay is 6 sec.
Because after the switch code completes its run, it will take a whole six seconds for the Arduino to come back to switch code in the loop because the wave signal of 3 sec on and 3 sec off should run.

if you want to run two tasks at the same time you need to learn the topics of millis() and protothreading.

---

You can ask me why I was this dumb to ask a question like this, because the only programming language I have ever snorted is python and in there I learned python is an interpreter and it executes line by line, Since Arduino ide code is built around c++ which is the compiler.

I thought the code won't run line by line instead the code will be compiled but now only I understood that even though the file is compiled there is no chance every code can be run at the same time as the actual meaning of the compiler.

Comment: I would suggest you do some research on the delay function so you understand why it is called a blocking function. The compiled code goes line by line as well. If you want to do two things at once you need two threads.  You can get the appearance of doing two things at once with multitasking. I have a feeling your code works as written, it only checks the switch every 6 seconds.

Comment: Yeah brother, i got it